# Cannot reference method from a static context error when attempting to output contents of linked list in instance class

Tags: java, static, linked-list

I'm a beginner Java programmer and I'm trying to check whether I've successfully copied an instance of Person in a linked list stored in class Clients to the linked list called passengers inside an instance of class Boat by having Boat print out the contents of it's linked list.

I am using the method givePassengers() from class Boat to have the Boat class printout it's passengers linked list contents.

However when I attempt to do so I am encountering the error 'non-static method givePassengers() cannot be referenced from a static context' and I'm not sure what to write to solve that problem. I've listed what I believe to be the problem code below. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I have marked important code with '// !!'

This is the class that contains the linked list of boats

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Base implements Serializable
{   private LinkedList<Boat> boats = new LinkedList<Boat>();
    private Clients clients = new Clients();

public void setup() // !! Here are the instances of the boat class
    {   boats.add(new Boat(1, "Ed", 2));
        boats.add(new Boat(2, "Fred", 7));
        boats.add(new Boat(3, "Freda", 5));   }


  public void showpassengers() {

        for (Boat i: boats) `// !! The for each loop cycles through each boat to check for passengers`
           Boat.givePassengers(); // !! This line produces the error
    }
```

Here is the boat class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Boat implements Serializable
{   private int id;
    private String pilot;
    private int stops;
    private LinkedList<Person> passengers = new LinkedList<Person>();
    private double rate = 10.00;
    public int scannableId = this.id;

 public Boat(int id, String pilot, int stops)
    {   this.id = id;
        this.pilot = pilot;
        this.stops = stops;   }



    public void givePassengers () {

System.out.println(passengers); // !! this line is supposed to print out the contents of the boat classes' linked list so I can check that it worked.

        }
```

Here is the Person class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Person implements Serializable
{   private String name;
    private int id;
    private double cash = 100.00;
    private int start = 0;
    private int end = 0;
    private double charge = 0;

   public Person(String name, int id)
    {   this.name = name;
        this.id = id + 100; }
}
```

Here is the class that contains the linked list of Person

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Clients implements Serializable
{   private LinkedList<Person> clients = new LinkedList<Person>();
    private int id = 1;

    public Clients() `// !! Here are the instances of Person in the class clients`
    {   clients.add(new Person("Homer", id++));
        clients.add(new Person("Marge", id++));  

    }
)
```

And here is the root class if that helps

```
import java.io.*;

public class Root
{   public Root() {

        new Base();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   new Root(); }


    private Base base;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for (Boat i: boats) 
   Boat.givePassengers(); // !! This line produces the error
```

You need to say `i.givePassengers()` to reference the specific instance of the class `Boat`. There's a good primer on the difference between classes and objects [here](http://java67.blogspot.com/2014/08/what-is-difference-between-class-and-object-java-programming-oops.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't call givePassengers() statically from Boat, it's not a static method. You need to call it from an instance of Boat. Replace `Boat.givePassengers();` with `i.givePassengers();` within your foreach loop. This will cause the currently selected Boat instance to run givePassengers().